# Spark MLlib collaborative filtering---how to view movie factors?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am working through this tutorial https://databricks-training.s3.amazonaws.com/movie-recommendation-with-mllib.html . How would one view the factors associated with each movie? In other words, how do I look at the model that has been trained?

Answer (score 3):

The `MatrixFactorizationModel` returned by ALS training basically consists of two RDDs, the user and product features. They are accessible publicly:

```
val userFeatures: RDD[(Int, Array[Double])] = model.userFeatures
val productFeatures: RDD[(Int, Array[Double])] = model.productFeatures
```

Both are RDDs of tuples where each tuple represents the userId/productId
and the features computed for this user/product.